# Python Image processing for finding overlapped part after stitching 2 images

Tags: python, image-processing

I am new in image processing I had got one task in image processing.. Firstly I have to add to images and then I had to find out out the overlapped part and secondly I had to find out the area which is not common. Code which I had tried:

```
from PIL import Image
image = Image.open('unsplash_01.jpg')
logo = Image.open('logo.png')
# img = logo.convert("RGBA")
new_image = logo.resize((100, 100))
image_copy = image.copy()
position = ((image_copy.width - new_image.width), (image_copy.height - new_image.height))
image_copy.paste(new_image, position, new_image)
image_copy.save('pasted_image.jpg')
```

But from this code I am just able to stitch 2 images but I not able to find the common area or uncommon area.
Any help will be appreciated.. Thanks
Images speak better then words so here is what I am trying.

[image]

[image]

result should be

[image]

Comment: What is your actual result/image?

Comment: last image which I had added

Comment: And what is your expected result\image?

Comment: Actually I am expecting last image but I am not getting it

Comment: I don't know how to get the overlapped part. Can you suggest some code for the same

Comment: I just wanted to stitch two images together and then from that stitched images I want  to find the overlapped part

Comment: Are images always black on while background?

Comment: No that's not necessary

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189879/discussion-between-alderven-and-pri).